# wget hangs after large file download

Tags: bash, wget

I'm trying to download a large file over a ftp. (5GB file). Here is my script.

```
read ZipName
wget -c -N -q --show-progress "ftp://Password@ftp.server.com/$ZipName"
unzip $ZipName
```

The files downloads at 100% but never goes to the unzip command. No special error message, no outputs in the terminal. Just blank new line. I have to send `CTRL + c` and run back to script to unzip since wget detects that the file is fully downloaded.

Why does is hangs out like this? Is it because of the large file, or passing an argument in command?

By the way I can't use `ftp` because it's not on the VM i'm working on, and it's a temporary VM so no root privilege to install anything.

Comment: Could you get to the point please.

Comment: sorry, i edited link address. maybe using -m option solve your problem.(--mirror ) (http://www.editcorp.com/personal/lars_appel/wget/v1/wget_7.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some tests, and I think that size of the disk was the reason.
I've tried with `curl -O` and it worked for the same disk space.